# How to split data file over hundreds of AWS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a json file with a tens of thousands of individual job details. These jobs can be executed by a single script and finish relatively quick.

I calculate that 500 instances in AWS will finish the job in under 1h minutes and keep my costs affordable.

How can I get each instance to run a different chunk of the data?

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the script doing the work?  If so, you could put the work into a SQS queue, have each machine pull off a single message, process it, and if there is more work to do, go back and get more work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to launch multiple EC2 instances from the same AMI in a single RunInstances request and have each EC2 instance read the same JSON file from S3.

Each instance would then [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) its own ami-launch-index from its metadata service. That ami-launch-index is going to be unique on each EC2 instance related to a given RunInstances request, and will be numbered from 0 to N-1 (where N is the number of instances that you launched).

Each EC2 instance could then process a subset of the list of jobs in the JSON file, based upon its local ami-launch-index (let's call that K), for example the jobs at index K, K + N, K + 2N, ...

Another option would be to write a script that parses the JSON file upfront, decide which jobs each of the N EC2 instances should  process, and then pass that subset of the list into each EC2 instance in userdata e.g. writing it to a json file on the instance. The application running on the instance would read that local file and process the relevant jobs.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod the ami-launch-index is exactly what I needed!